# Line Chart Display by Month with all Date information being reported as XX/XX/XXXX

Tags: sql, charts, oracle-apex, apex

Below is a chart I made in Apex. Since the form I use to create this chart uses a date picker entry it automatically graphs it by day. Is there a where clause or a sequel code I should use instead of the settings I am currently using? The goal of this graph is to show the sum of the total cost by month.

```
    select SCRAP_DATE,  
           CHARGED_COST,
    from SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM
```

[image]

Here is a picture of the setting I am currently using
[image]

Comment: There most probably is a way to show data by month. Can you update your question and add the current source sql in your question pls ?

Comment: select SCRAP_DATE,  
                   CHARGED_COST,                                                                                        
        from SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to

```
    select TO_CHAR(SCRAP_DATE,'YYYY-MM') AS YM,
           TO_CHAR(SCRAP_DATE,'MON') AS MON,
           SUM(CHARGED_COST) AS CHARGED_COST
    from SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM
      GROUP BY TO_CHAR(SCRAP_DATE,'YYYY-MM'), TO_CHAR(SCRAP_DATE,'MON')
      ORDER BY TO_CHAR(SCRAP_DATE,'YYYY-MM')
```

Use "MON" as label. The order by is needed to ensure correct order